# Casting object pointer to double void pointer (pointer to pointer to void)

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, type-conversion, pointer-to-pointer

I have a class method in a library (can't change it) which takes a double void pointer as one of its arguments. The declaration is as follows:

```
bool Queue::pop(void **packet, int &size, unsigned short &sn)
```

In my application code, I want to pass this function a pointer to another kind of object, in this case a [GstBuffer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstbuffer.html?gi-language=c) pointer type. It seems like I can do this without any compiler errors if I cast the pointer to `(void**)` as in the following snippet but I have doubts if that will lead to correct behaviour. Is it valid to convert the pointer like this?

```
guint16 sn;
int size;
GstBuffer *buf; 
Queue *Q = ... // create a Queue instance
Q->pop((void **)&buf, size, sn);  // is this conversion valid?
size = gst_buffer_get_size(buf);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all intents and purposes a `void` pointer can hold addresses of any object (data type), ***i.e.*** it can point to any object, and can be typecasted to any object, your code is valid, I would just use a more idiomatic cast:

```
Q->pop(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&buf), size, sn);
```

#### §7.3.12 Pointer conversions [conv.ptr]

> 2. *A prvalue of type “pointer to cv `T`”, where `T` is an object type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv `void`”. The pointer value (6.8.3) is unchanged by this conversion.*

[Example:](https://godbolt.org/z/av3Tc9PY3)

```
void example(void **packet){
    std::cout << *packet << "\n";                   // pointer value
    std::cout << packet << "\n";                    // pointer address
    std::cout << **reinterpret_cast<int**>(packet); // value
}

int main() 
{
    int* x = new int(20);
    std::cout << x << "\n";                         // pointer value
    std::cout << &x << "\n";                        // pointer address
    example(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&x));       
    delete x;
}
```

Output:

```
0xb83eb0
0x7ffc181ab2c8
0xb83eb0
0x7ffc181ab2c8
20
```

The explicit cast is even only needed because it's a pointer to pointer otherwise the conversion would be implicit, no cast would be needed.

Comment: @PluginPenguin you're absolutely right, smart pointers are way better but for the intent of this answer, I felt it was unneeded to use it, it is worth mentioning it though.